# Calculate (subtracted) differences between two collections containing month-grouped data

Tags: php, laravel, difference

1. Calculate sum of `cost` from the `Finance` model grouped by `month`.

   ```
   $data1  = Finance::select(         
        \DB::raw('SUM(cost) as finances_monthly'),
        \DB::raw('(unit) as unit'),
        \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as months")
    )
    ->where('unit', '=', $unit)
    ->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->orderBy('date','asc')
    ->groupby('months','unit')->get();
   ```
2. Calculate sum of `deposite` from the `Accounting` model grouped by `month`.

   ```
   $data2 =  $MonthlyPayments  = Accounting::select(
       \DB::raw('SUM(deposite) as deposites_monthly'),
       \DB::raw('(unit) as unit'),
       \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(payment_date,'%M %Y') as month")
   )
   ->where('unit', '=', $unit)
   ->orderBy('created_at','asc')
   ->whereBetween('payment_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
   ->groupby('month','unit')->get();
   ```
3. Calculate the (subtracted) difference between `deposite` and `cost` and grouped by `month`.

   My problem is here. I don't know how to perform the month-specific subtraction.

Comment: This question would be clearer if there was sample data as part of a [mcve].  If we understood the schema, there might be a way to do this solely in SQL.  Otherwise if the calculation is to be done in PHP, then we could use some sample collections to play with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_diff() to resolve this problem, but you should make sure the fields of both arrays are same;

```
$data1 = $data1->toArray();
$data2 = $data2->toArray();
$diff_data = array_diff($data1, $data2);
```

Comment: you can try $data1->diff($data2)

Comment: I don't see how this answer even attempts to resolve: `how to subtract deposites_monthly from finances_monthly and groupBy months`.